# Why I can not install new maven?

Tags: java, maven

I download a new maven and execute using the full path, but still get the old version, and it doesn't help even I put it on PATH. It's very weird.

I run the maven as version of 3.3.9, but it still use the 3.2.5

```
-bash-4.1#  /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Do you need to run `rehash` to invalidate your path cache and see the new version?

Comment: Weird. Can you output the `ls -la` and `stat` of your new `mvn` ?

Comment: You are sure you extracted the right maven version in this directory?

Comment: Only add `../apache-maven-3.3.9/bin` to your path...don't set `M2_HOME` ...not needed...(apart from JAVA_HOME)..

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. Only set M2_HOME works for me

Answer (score 0):

M2_HOME is set as the old maven home directory. Seems maven will pick up the MAVEN from this environment variable.